# bandwidth limits to google apps script doPost?

Tags: post, google-apps-script, quota

I'm aware that POST requests for files and other data can be made through a script published as a Google Apps Script, the question is I couldn't find any information regarding the maximum amount of size per file, and / or if there were any other bandwidth restrictions for doPost.

Comment: There is no public documentation that gives a hard limit for `doPost()`, though it seems that the `multipart/form-data` type [can't be used with `doPost()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42217052) so you'll have to convert uploads to base64 first. HTTP POST doesn't have a limit in its specification but web server implementation may impose limits. As there's no official documentation on this I'd suggest attempting to upload bigger and bigger files using th example in the link and seeing at what point you hit a wall.

Comment: Also, just to clear things up: bandwidth refers to [maximum data transfer *rate*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandwidth_(computing)) which is going to be down to factors like connection type, network provider, etc, not server-side POST request limitations.

Answer (score -1):

Please see [Apps Script Quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations)

The URL Fetch POST size can be 50 MB per call. You can make up 20,000 URL Fetch calls per day   with a Gmail account and 50,000 per day with GSuite (paid) Google accounts.

Comment: is URL Fetch Post referring to the UrlFetchAPP or post requests made *to* the app through doPost?

Comment: @justme UrlFetchApp

Comment: The question concerns the quota limits for doPost, not relating to UrlFetchApp; rather, other post requests made *to* the script *from* other sources