# I want to upload img from local to drive and save url in sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I want to upload img from local to drive and save url in sheet
i use this code to upload img to drive but now i want get url and save in sparedsheet

---

this gs code for app script can any one help to get url and stop app script complete page
this i will run it from local html please help me

```
    function doGet(e) {
  return message("Error: no parameters");
}

function doPost(e) {
   var template = HtmlService
                 .createTemplateFromFile('ModalForm');

  var htmlOutput = template.evaluate()
                   .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE)
                   .setTitle('done ');
  if (!e.parameters.filename || !e.parameters.file || !e.parameters.imageformat) {
    return message("Error: Bad parameters");
    
  } else {
    var imgf = e.parameters.imageformat[0].toUpperCase();
    var mime =
        (imgf == 'BMP')  ? MimeType.BMP
      : (imgf == 'GIF')  ? MimeType.GIF
     : (imgf == 'JPEG') ? MimeType.JPEG
     : (imgf == 'PNG')  ? MimeType.PNG
      : (imgf == 'SVG')  ? MimeType.SVG
      : false;
    if (mime) {
      var data = Utilities.base64Decode(e.parameters.file, Utilities.Charset.UTF_8);
      var blob = Utilities.newBlob(data, mime, e.parameters.filename);
    var as=  DriveApp.getFolderById('1myWqX4qCtsFYOPvTl9vT7Xa1inzAG6Rc').createFile(blob);
Logger.log(as.getUrl());
    }
    else {
      return message("Error: Bad image format");
    }
  }
}
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

You can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42217817) to build a working solution that uploads a 'PNG'. Change the `mimetype` as needed.

### Suggested modification

```
// Code.gs
function doGet(e) {
  return message("Error: no parameters");
}

function doPost(e) {
  if (!e.parameters.filename || !e.parameters.file) {
    return message("Error: Bad parameters");
  } else {
    var data = Utilities.base64Decode(e.parameters.file, Utilities.Charset.UTF_8);
    var blob = Utilities.newBlob(data, MimeType.PNG, e.parameters.filename);
    var file = DriveApp.getFolderById('1myWqX4qCtsFYOPvTl9vT7Xa1inzAG6Rc').createFile(blob);
    var url = file.getUrl();
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("your-spreadsheet-id").getSheetByName("sheet-name");
    sheet.appendRow([url]);
    return message("completed");
  }
}

function message(msg) {
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({result: msg})).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

### References

[MIME Types](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/mime-type)

[SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)